# Converting characters in different languages

Tags: javascript, c#

I have written the following program in two different languages.  I have it working in one, except I'm stuck on one part in the other.

In C#:

```
object a(dynamic a) {
    dynamic b = "00000000".ToCharArray(), c = 7;
    while (a > 0) {
        b[c--] = (a ^ 1) > (a + ((a >>= 1) * 0)) ? '0' : '1';
    }
    return b;
}
object v = a(11), n = b(v);
object b(dynamic b) {
    dynamic a = 0, c;
    for (c = a; c < 8; c++) {
        a += b[c] == '0' ? 0 : 1 << (7 ^ c);
    }
    return a;
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
function a(a) {
    b = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'];
    c = 7;
    while (a > 0) {
        b[c--] = (a ^ 1) > (a + ((a >>= 1) * 0)) ? '0' : '1'
    }
    return b
}

function B(b) {
    a = b ^ b;
    for (c = a; c < 8; c++) {
        a += b[c] == '0' ? 0 : 1 << (7 ^ c)
    }
    return a
}
```

In C#, I get the following correct input.

```
a(11)=00001011 // correct

b(a)=11 // correct


a('M')=01001101 // correct

(char)b(a)='M' // correct
```

In JavaScript, I get all zeroes when I pass in a letter.

```
a(11)=00001011 // correct

B(a)=11 // correct


a(‘M’)=00000000 // incorrect

B(a)=0 // incorrect because first function was incorrect
```

I've tried reading over the logic over and again, except I'm stuck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In javascript: `'M' ^ 1` returns `1` - in C#, it returns `76`

Comment: do you realise that the quotes are different in those two a('M') and a(‘M’) and quotes have their own different values.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought single quotes and double for strings worked in JavaScript like they did in C#.  I thought 'M' was the same in each language.

Comment: When you execute the second JavaScript function it *overwrites* the first one, because it assigns a new value to `a` that replace the function `a()`. You need to declare your variables with a `var` statement to make them local within the function.